# Why does decision tree give wrong classification in R?

Tags: r, statistics, decision-tree

As a result of creating a decision tree for Fisher's iris data I've got misclassification error rate: 0.02667 = 4 / 150. But I see only 3 mistakes on my plot:
[DS for the iris](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8bOZ.png).

If we look at probabilities for this point - it's ok(virginica - the same as on the plot above):

```
   setosa versicolor  virginica
   0      0.1666667   0.83333333
```

Can you explain why this misclassification happened (4 mistakes instead of 3 that are clearly delineated on the plot) ?

Code:

```
# install.packages("tree")
# install.packages("ggplot2")

library('tree')
library('ggplot2') 

data(iris)

iris <- iris[ , c('Petal.Length', 'Petal.Width', 'Species')]
myTree <- tree(Species ~ Petal.Length + Petal.Width, data = iris)
summary(myTree)

# Classification tree:
# tree(formula = Species ~ Petal.Length + Petal.Width, data = iris)
# Number of terminal nodes:  5 
# Residual mean deviance:  0.157 = 22.77 / 145 
# Misclassification error rate: 0.02667 = 4 / 150 

# The errors were found by comparing predict(myTree, iris, type="class")
# with native data set 
errors <- data.frame(
Species = c('versicolor', 'versicolor', 'versicolor', 'virginica'),
Petal.Length = c(4.8, 5.0, 5.1, 4.5), Petal.Width = c(1.8, 1.7, 1.6, 1.7))

ggplot(iris, aes(x = Petal.Length, y = Petal.Width, colour = Species)) + 
 geom_point(size = 2.1) +
 geom_vline(xintercept = 2.45) +
 geom_hline(yintercept = 1.75) +
 geom_vline(xintercept = 4.95) + 
 geom_point(data = errors, shape = 1, size = 5,colour = "black")
```

Comment: You're going to need to share the code you used to build the model and get your predictions.  Otherwise the best we can do is say that you either coded it wrong or are interpreting some of the output wrong.

Comment: Please specify any packages you use and include the code for loading them.  Side note: why are you calling the tree DT? Typically that implies that the object is a data.table. Also explain how you're determining which you think are misclassified.

Comment: I would suggest adding the code you used to make your graph and the code you used to figure out which ones were misclassified.  Note that there is more than one observation with petal length = 4.8 and petal.width = 1.8

Comment: ... I didn't want you to manually construct the errors data.frame.  That doesn't help at all - I was trying to get you to show what code you used to figure out which were errors... Either way - look at my answer - there isn't an error being made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point you're looking at isn't misclassified.

But there are multiple observations at that point and they don't all have the same species.  Adding some jitter to the plot...

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Petal.Length, y = Petal.Width, colour = Species)) +
   geom_point(position = "jitter") +
   geom_vline(xintercept = 4.95) + geom_vline(xintercept = 2.45) + geom_hline(yintercept = 1.75)
```

and you'll see what's actually going on.

From the data...

```
> iris[iris$Petal.Length == 4.8 & iris$Petal.Width == 1.8,]
    Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
71           4.8         1.8 versicolor
127          4.8         1.8  virginica
139          4.8         1.8  virginica
```